# Function InsertBefore() on Double Linked Circular List in Golang

Tags: list, go, linked-list, insert

I am implementing a double linked circular list in Golang and I have the following problem, I was able to correctly assemble the InsertAfter() function to add values ​​to the list and it contains the following structure:

```golang
package main

type Node struct {
    Value int
    Next  *Node
    Prev  *Node
}

func CreateList(n int) *Node {
    nn := &Node{
        Value: n,
        Next:  nil,
        Prev:  nil,
    }
    nn.Next = nn
    nn.Prev = nn

    return nn
}

func InsertAfter(p *Node, value int) *Node {
    nn := &Node{Value: value}
    q := p.Next
    p.Next = nn
    nn.Next = q
    q.Prev = nn
    nn.Prev = p

    return nn
}

func main() {
    L := CreateList(3)
    x := InsertAfter(L, 7)
    InsertAfter(x, 11)
    k := InsertBefore(x, 5) //This (when it works) should insert the value 5 before the value 7
}
```

After this I insert 3 int values ​​in the list using this function (values ​​3, 7 and 11) but I need to create a function (called InsertBefore()) respecting the structure of the previous function and fulfilling the inverse function to this and insert a value before, I was able to create a part of this but it does not work (it is below), Would you please tell me where i have failed or what I am missing to complete it? Thank you.

```golang
func InsertBefore(p *Node, value int) *Node {

    nn := &Node{Value: value}
    q := p.Prev
    p.Prev = nn
    nn.Prev = q
    q.Next = nn
    nn.Next = p

    return nn
}
```

Comment: It works for me: https://play.golang.org/p/fM1gtRTTm4b.

Comment: "but it does not work" is not an actionable problem description.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some workarounds for the code. I think this is working now.

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
    )
    
    type Node struct {
        Value int
        Next *Node
        Prev *Node
    }
    
    func CreateList(n int) *Node {
        nn := &Node{
            Value: n,
            Next: nil,
            Prev: nil,
        }
        nn.Next = nn
        nn.Prev = nn
    
        return nn
    }
    
    
    func (p *Node)InsertAfter(value int) *Node {
        nn := &Node{Value: value}
        nn.Prev = p
        nn.Next = p.Next
    
        //if p is not the last element in the list
        //its next.previous should be new node
        if p.Next.Prev != p.Next {
            p.Next.Prev = nn
        }
    
        p.Next = nn
    
        return nn
    }
    
    func printList(p *Node) {
        n := p
        for {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf(`node %v, prev %v, next %v`, n, n.Prev.Value, n.Next.Value))
            n = n.Next
            if n == p {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    func (p *Node)InsertBefore(value int) *Node {
        nn := &Node{Value: value}
        nn.Next = p
        nn.Prev = p.Prev
        if p.Prev == p {
            //this means this is the root
            //so we need to update last node's next
            n := p
            for {
                if n.Next == p {
                    n.Next = nn
                    break
                }
                n = n.Next
            }
            nn.Prev = nn
        } else {
            p.Prev.Next = nn
        }
        p.Prev = nn
        return nn
    
    }
    
    func main() {
        L := CreateList(3)
        x := L.InsertBefore(7)
    
        x.InsertAfter(11)
        x.InsertBefore(5)
    
        fmt.Println(`final list`)
        printList(x)
    }

//Output: -
//final list
//node &{7 0xc00000c060 0xc00000c078}, prev 5, next 11
//node &{11 0xc00000c030 0xc00000c048}, prev 7, next 3
//node &{3 0xc00000c078 0xc00000c060}, prev 11, next 5
//node &{5 0xc00000c048 0xc00000c078}, prev 5, next 7
```

You can run code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/hQGD4ez31FA)